# Object URL mapping in JavaScript / TypeScript / Angular4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a class for `SearchFilter`

```
class SearchFilter { 
   constructor(bucket: string,
               pin: number,
               qty: number,
               category: string) {
   }
}
```

When user hits search I'm filling in the filter to matrix params.

```
router.navigate(['filter', searchFilter]); //searchFilter is an instance
```

The URL looks like

```
filter;bucket=MPC123;category=JOINT;qty=90;pin=9087
```

This is being used in another component where the **param** is mapped back to an `Object` of type `SearchFilter`. But here the data types need to be set explicitly as far as I know.

```
   const params = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params;
   const filter = this.getFilterFromParams(params);
```

---

```
   getFilterFromParams(params) :SearchFilter {
      const filter = new SearchFilter();
      Object.keys(params).forEach((key) => {
         switch(key) {
             case 'pin':
             case 'qty': filter[key] = Number(params[key]); break;
             default: filter[key] = params[key];
         }
      });
      return filter;
   }
```

As seen from above code, to map the params back to Object a custom mapping function is written, **the question is if there is any other obvious way this can be done or is this a common pattern?**

I will have to depend on URL as users should be able to share URLs of different filters.

Comment: Is there a question here somewhere?

Comment: @JGFMK "the question is if there is any other obvious way this can be done or is this a common pattern?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a static factory method would work:

```
class SearchFilter { 
  constructor(
    bucket: string,
    pin: number,
    qty: number,
    category: string) {
  }

  public static fromParams({ bucket, pin, qty, category }) {
    // TODO Add validation to ensure pin & qty are integers
    return new SearchFilter(
      bucket,
      parseInt(pin),
      parseInt(qty),
      category);
  }
}
```

Then we can use it like this:

```
const demoParams = {
  bucket: "MPC123",
  category: "JOINT",
  qty: "90",
  pin: "9087"
};

const filter = SearchFilter.fromParams(demoParams);
```

Comment: In `demoParams` `qty` and `pin` will be string in my case like, `qty: "90"`. I do have `Date` types as well.

Comment: @sabithpocker For `qty` and `pin`, you can use the `parseInt` function as indicated in the edit to this answer. For the `Date`, you can use a similar technique.

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe go for the capabilities of `Object.assign` and the spread syntax:

```
getFilterFromParams(params) :SearchFilter {
    return Object.assign(new SearchFilter(), params,
        ...['pin', 'qty'].map(key => key in params && { [key]: Number(params[key]) })
    );
}
```

Comment: Interesting alternative. so anyway we will have to do this explicitly using a function right? No possible way like say encode/decode URL?

Comment: No, there is no built in function for that. However, if you would be open to change the way you format the parameters in the URL, you could pass JSON. That will maintain the data type, and can be decoded/encoded with one or two function calls. It just doesn't look that nice in the URL...

Comment: Can you please add an example with that, I cannot imagine how the datatypes will be preserved in URL. I have cases like `kpn: "234"` where `kpn` is a string of digits which should remain as string when converting back.

Comment: I was thinking of `router.navigate(['filter', { json: JSON.stringify(searchFilter) }])` for sending, and `return Object.assign(new SearchFilter(), JSON.parse(params.json))` for the receiving part.

Comment: ...but I read your other comment where you say you have Dates as well: JSON has no Date type, so that will not help you then. It would be good if you would edit your question and add a Date in the example.

Comment: I am converting date to string using `moment` explicitly before `router.navigate` and then converting back using moment, I'll add that code but it will make the example complex?.

Comment: Is it possible to write a reusable solution in `typescript` where a URL parameter can be cast to the datatypes defined in typescript for any Class. I understand that datatypes are only for typescript, just wondering.