# Angular2 persisting search filters in URL

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to persist some filters that will be used in my application to the url, so that when I will reload the page I could read them and re-apply them. I'm having some problems with Dates(I'm using moment), nullable properties and special characters (`/`).
Since everything that I send to the url as `extraParameters` using this code: `this.router.navigate(['page/page2', params]);` get converted to string, when I try to read the values I get `"null"` or `"false"` `"%2F"`. Is this simply as it this and I need to be aware of the type of each one and cast them accordingly? Is there a smarter way to do this stuff?
Right now I'm simply handling all of them as strings, and then parsing them back like this:

```
  saveUrlParams() {
    const urlParams: DeadLineUrlParameters = {
      page: this.searchParams.page.toString(),
      pageSize: this.searchParams.pageSize.toString(),
      term: this.searchParams.term,
      onlyHandled: this.searchParams.onlyHandled,
      onlyNotHandled: this.searchParams.onlyNotHandled,
      from: this.searchParams.from ? new Date(this.searchParams.from).toDateString() : '',
      to: this.searchParams.to ? new Date(this.searchParams.to).toDateString() : '',
    };
    this.router.navigate(['page/page2', urlParams]);
  }
```

and then parsing them back:

```
const params = this.route.snapshot.params;
const test: DeadlineSearchParams = {
  term: params.term,
  onlyNotHandled: params.onlyNotHandled === 'true',
  from: new Date(decodeURI(params.from))
}
```

Comment: You're using decodeURI, there should also be a function [`encodeURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).

Comment: i've used sessionStorage that clears upon reload with some success. allows you `stringify` and `parse` your params.

Comment: @Rich Yes, but it seems that navigate already handles the encoding so there is no need to do that

Answer (score 0):

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45663433/object-url-mapping-in-javascript-typescript-angular4) that I asked sometime back. Refer the answers there as well.

URL only support strings and so **type is lost** when converting to URL. Only thing I can think of is to infer a type by using Regular Expression which would be hard and can have a lot of edge cases. I may be ignorant though!

I do something like the following using `date-fns` to get `Date` object back:

```
createFilterFromParams(params: any): MyFilter {
    const filter = new MyFilter();
    Object.keys(params).forEach(key => {
      switch (key) {
        case 'p1':
        case 'p2':
        case 'page': filter[key] = params[key] ? Number(params[key]) : params[key]; break;
        case 'dateFrom':
        case 'dateTo': filter[key] = params[key] ? format(parse(params[key]), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss') : null; break;
        default: filter[key] = params[key];
      }
    });
    return filter;
  }
```

And yes, formats before setting them to URL.. something like:

```
if (filter.dateFrom) {
  cleanParams.dateFrom = format(startOfDay(parse(filter.dateFrom)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
}
if (filter.dateTo) {
  cleanParams.dateTo = format(endOfDay(parse(filter.dateTo)), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
}
```